# Hiding Vertical Scrollbar in wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I have a wx.TextCtrl that I am using to represent a display with a fixed number of character rows and columns. I would like to hide the vertical scrollbar that is displayed to the right of the text pane since it is entirely unnecessary in my application. Is there a way to achieve this?

Also...I would like to hide the blinking cursor that is displayed in the pane. Unfortunately, `wx.TextCtrl.GetCaret()` is returning `None` so I cannot call `wx.Caret.Hide()`.

Environment info:

- Windows XP
- Python 2.5
- wxPython 2.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting the style `wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL` for the wx.TxtCtrl?

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks. For some reason, TE_NO_VSCROLL is not a documented style in the doc set I am using.

Comment: No effect at all here :-( (wxPython 2.8.10 on Ubuntu karmic)

Comment: Indeed, implementation seems sporadic:
No effect on Win7, python2.7, wxpython 2.8.12.1
works on Linux, python 2.4, wxpython 2.8.12.0
Probably the reason it hasn't been documented.  Dev beware, I guess.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Windows 8, python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0